# Customize Dialog Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material ui dialog, and i want to insert a table inside dialog.
Can I do that?

```
                      <Button
                        variant="contained"
                        color="secondary"
                        onClick={this.handleOpenDialog}
                      >
                        Cancel
                      </Button>
                      <Dialog
                        agree={() =>
                          this.handleCloseDialog
                        }
                        open={this.state.openDialog}
                        title="Are you sure?"
                        dialog="Your data will be deleted!"
                        onClose={this.handleCloseDialog}
                      ></Dialog>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the table inside a DialogContent component within your dialog: https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/#AlertDialog.js

Comment: what is MatDialogContent, i only see DialogContent and DialogContentText

Comment: That was a typo. Use DialogContent.